# Load wav local file into WebAudio

Tags: javascript, webrtc, web-audio-api

I want to load a .wav file which I have loaded like this:

```
var selectedFile = document.getElementById('input').files[0];
```

I want to load it into an `AudioContext` for using it later as an stream source for my WebRTC application.

I have tried using File reader to read as `ArrayBuffer` for later loading with `DecodeAudioData` into the context, but I don't get that to work.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I have tried like this

```
 var selectedFile = document.getElementById('input').files[0];

  //Creamos el lector de fichero
  var reader = new FileReader();
  //Leemos el fichero como un buffer
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(selectedFile);
  // Esperamos a que termine de leer
  while (reader.readyState !=2){

  }
  //Guardamos el resultado de la lectura
  var buffer= reader.result;
  //Creamos el contexto que luego introducira el audio en el peer
  var context = new AudioContext();

  context.decodeAudioData(buffer, function(audio) {
   var AudioBuffer=audio;
  },

  function(e){"Error with decoding audio data" + e.err});
```

and like this

```
 var selectedFile = document.getElementById('input').files[0];

  //Creamos el lector de fichero
  var reader = new FileReader();




       // Closure to capture the file information.
  reader.onload = function () {
       var data = reader.result;
       var buffer = new Int8Array(data);
      output.value = JSON.stringify(array, null, '  ');
     window.setTimeout(ReadFile, 1000);
      };

  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(selectedFile);


  //Guardamos el resultado de la lectura
  var buffer= reader.result;
   console.log("Guarda resultado de la lectura");
  //Creamos el contexto que luego introducira el audio en el peer
  var context = new AudioContext();
   console.log("Contexto creado");
  context.decodeAudioData(buffer, function(audio) {
     console.log("Descodificado");
   var AudioBuffer=audio;
    console.log("asignado");
  },

  function(e){"Error with decoding audio data" + e.err});
```

Comment: _"I have tried using File reader to read as ArrayBuffer for later loading with DecodeAudioData into the context, but I don't get that to work."_ Can you describe "don't get that to work", and include full `javascript` that you tried at Question?

Comment: Yeah, you're going to have to include a bunch more source.  I think maybe you're trying to do local file upload?  In that case, you don't have the data itself loaded.

Comment: Added thed the code I used, didn't want to upload it because I can feel my code is so horrible.